# Update TFS15 preview to TFS15 RC2 Data Tier error

Tags: tfs, updates

while configuring update from TFS 15 preview to RC2 i get this error in readiness check tab

> The configuration database that you specified cannot be upgraded. The
>   following issue prevents upgrading the database: TF400965: The
>   database was created using a non-Go Live version of Team Foundation
>   Server and cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as yours when upgrade from TFS 15 preview to RC. As the error message indicates, TFS 15 preview can't be upgraded to RC version. You need to create a new database instance to install a new installation for TFS RC version.

---

**Add:**

Please check this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/08/team-foundation-server-15-preview-released/

> We have released the first preview of Team Foundation Server “15”, our
>   next major version of TFS.  This preview is not go-live, which means
>   it is not licensed to be installed on production systems.  Upgrading
>   from this version to future versions will be blocked and unsupported.